# How do i get all the stops from this XML? Windows phone

Tags: xml, windows-phone-7

I have a feed and this is the XML that I get from the feed : All i am intrested in is the routename (  and  and the content within the   nodes

```
<Route z:Id="i1" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/BusExpress.ClassLibrary" 
xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
<EntityKey z:Id="i2"  
xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Objects.DataClasses"  
xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data"> 
<a:EntityContainerName>busExpressEntities</a:EntityContainerName>
<a:EntityKeyValues>
  <a:EntityKeyMember>
    <a:Key>routeId</a:Key>
    <a:Value i:type="b:int" xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">1231</a:Value>
  </a:EntityKeyMember>
</a:EntityKeyValues>
<a:EntitySetName>RouteSet</a:EntitySetName>
</EntityKey>
<POI />
<POILines />
<dateEffectiveFrom i:nil="true" />
<dateEffectiveTo i:nil="true" />
<isLive>true</isLive>
<relativePosition>0</relativePosition>
<routeDescription />
<routeId>1231</routeId>
<routeMap />
<routeName>1 Whitehawk - Mile Oak</routeName>
<route_stop>
<route_stop z:Id="i3">
<EntityKey z:Id="i4" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Objects.DataClasses" xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data">
    <a:EntityContainerName>busExpressEntities</a:EntityContainerName>
    <a:EntityKeyValues>
      <a:EntityKeyMember>
        <a:Key>routeId</a:Key>
        <a:Value i:type="b:int" xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">1231</a:Value>
      </a:EntityKeyMember>
      <a:EntityKeyMember>
        <a:Key>stopId</a:Key>
        <a:Value i:type="b:int" xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">6882</a:Value>
      </a:EntityKeyMember>
    </a:EntityKeyValues>
    <a:EntitySetName>route_stop</a:EntitySetName>
  </EntityKey>
  <alightingTariffCode>1</alightingTariffCode>
  <boardingTariffCode>1</boardingTariffCode>
  <route z:Ref="i1" />
  <routeId>1231</routeId>
  <routeIndex>1</routeIndex>
  <routeReference xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Objects.DataClasses">
    <a:EntityKey z:Ref="i2" xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data" />
  </routeReference>
  <stop z:Id="i5">
    <EntityKey z:Id="i6" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Objects.DataClasses" xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data">
      <a:EntityContainerName>busExpressEntities</a:EntityContainerName>
      <a:EntityKeyValues>
        <a:EntityKeyMember>
          <a:Key>stopId</a:Key>
          <a:Value i:type="b:int" xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">6882</a:Value>
        </a:EntityKeyMember>
      </a:EntityKeyValues>
      <a:EntitySetName>StopSet</a:EntitySetName>
    </EntityKey>
    <AtcoCode>149000006612</AtcoCode>
    <GPSStopName>Swanborough Dr.</GPSStopName>
    <Lat>50.8326729229821</Lat>
    <Long>-0.103217996656901</Long>
    <LongName>Swanborough Drive</LongName>
    <NaptanCode>bridmpj</NaptanCode>
    <OperatorsCode1>06612</OperatorsCode1>
    <OperatorsCode2>6612</OperatorsCode2>
    <OperatorsCode3>51581</OperatorsCode3>
    <OperatorsCode4>bridmpj</OperatorsCode4>
    <StopName>Swanborough Drive</StopName>
    <route_stop>
      <route_stop z:Ref="i3" />
    </route_stop>
    <route_stop_stop />
    <route_stop_timetable_stop />
    <stopId>6882</stopId>
  </stop>
  <stopId>6882</stopId>
  <stopReference xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Objects.DataClasses">
    <a:EntityKey z:Ref="i6" xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data" />
  </stopReference>
</route_stop>
<route_stop z:Id="i7">
  <EntityKey z:Id="i8" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Objects.DataClasses" xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data">
    <a:EntityContainerName>busExpressEntities</a:EntityContainerName>
    <a:EntityKeyValues>
      <a:EntityKeyMember>
        <a:Key>routeId</a:Key>
        <a:Value i:type="b:int" xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">1231</a:Value>
      </a:EntityKeyMember>
      <a:EntityKeyMember>
        <a:Key>stopId</a:Key>
        <a:Value i:type="b:int" xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">6883</a:Value>
      </a:EntityKeyMember>
    </a:EntityKeyValues>
    <a:EntitySetName>route_stop</a:EntitySetName>
  </EntityKey>
  <alightingTariffCode>1</alightingTariffCode>
  <boardingTariffCode>1</boardingTariffCode>
  <route z:Ref="i1" />
  <routeId>1231</routeId>
  <routeIndex>2</routeIndex>
  <routeReference xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Objects.DataClasses">
    <a:EntityKey z:Ref="i2" xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data" />
  </routeReference>
  <stop z:Id="i9">
    <EntityKey z:Id="i10" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Objects.DataClasses" xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data">
      <a:EntityContainerName>busExpressEntities</a:EntityContainerName>
      <a:EntityKeyValues>
        <a:EntityKeyMember>
          <a:Key>stopId</a:Key>
          <a:Value i:type="b:int" xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">6883</a:Value>
        </a:EntityKeyMember>
      </a:EntityKeyValues>
      <a:EntitySetName>StopSet</a:EntitySetName>
    </EntityKey>
    <AtcoCode>149000006613</AtcoCode>
    <GPSStopName>Haybourne Road</GPSStopName>
    <Lat>50.8317788816436</Lat>
    <Long>-0.10486427645364671</Long>
    <LongName>Haybourne Road</LongName>
    <NaptanCode>brimapm</NaptanCode>
    <OperatorsCode1>06613</OperatorsCode1>
    <OperatorsCode2>6613</OperatorsCode2>
    <OperatorsCode3>51701</OperatorsCode3>
    <OperatorsCode4>brimapm</OperatorsCode4>
    <StopName>Haybourne Road</StopName>
    <route_stop>
      <route_stop z:Ref="i7" />
    </route_stop>
    <route_stop_stop />
    <route_stop_timetable_stop />
    <stopId>6883</stopId>
  </stop>
  <stopId>6883</stopId>
  <stopReference xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Objects.DataClasses">
    <a:EntityKey z:Ref="i10" xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data" />
  </stopReference>
</route_stop>
</Route>
```

I have the following code to get the URL -

```
 WebClient client = new WebClient(); 
    client.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(client_OpenReadCompleted);
    Uri url = new Uri("http://www.buscms.com/brightonbuses/v1/route.aspx?routeid=1231&stops=true&maps=true", UriKind.Absolute); 
    client.OpenReadAsync(url);
```

What's the next stop in this part

```
public void client_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

So that I am able to get the stops in the xml that is in the url?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a start, I wouldn't use the OpenRead method, I would go with DownloadString instead, so your initial call would be:

```
        void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadStringCompleted);
        Uri url = new Uri("http://www.buscms.com/brightonbuses/v1/route.aspx?routeid=1231&stops=true&maps=true", UriKind.Absolute);
        client.DownloadStringAsync(url);
    }
```

And your event handler would then look like this

```
void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            if (e.Result != null)
            {
                XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
                XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/BusExpress.ClassLibrary";
                var routeNames = (from n in doc.Descendants(ns + "Route")
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     RouteName = n.Element(ns + "routeName").Value,
                                     Stops = (from s in n.Element(ns + "route_stop").Elements(ns + "route_stop")
                                              select new
                                              {
                                                  StopCode = s.Element(ns + "stop").Element(ns + "OperatorsCode4").Value,
                                                  StopName = s.Element(ns + "stop").Element(ns + "StopName").Value
                                                  StopId = s.Element(ns + "stop").Element(ns + "stopId").Value

                                              }).ToList()
                                 }).Single();


                listBusStops.ItemsSource = routeNames.Stops;

                // Do something with the list of Route Names in routeNames
            }
        }
    }
```

Note the use of the XNamespace in order to find the routeName tags.

Don't forget to add a reference to System.Xml.Linq to your project.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I was supposd to say also the StopName as well. and then put this into a list box.

Would the list box be somethign like this - listBusStops = routeNames;

Comment: listBusStops.ItemsSource = routeNames;

Is your intention to have the RouteName and the StopName as part of the same listbox?

Comment: My aim is to output the routename in a text block with the list of bus stops as a list below it. Then the user selects that bus stop, this then goes to another xml feed and selects the correct stop and displays the times.

Comment: But i would like the NaptanCode next to the list of StopName so for example it would be    Swanborough Drive (bridmpj)

Comment: Right, so really you need to create yourself a class that has two properties, a string for Name, and a List<string> for the stops and then parse the xml in a similar fashion to my example above. Your listbox would then be listBusStops.ItemsSource = myRoute.Stops;

Comment: Ok, thanks, how would i put in a Where so that I can select a stop depending on a conidition. So select the stopname and the naptan code where the stopcode is equaled to 6882

Comment: Have changed my linq query to give you some anonymous types, this could of course be changed to use your own classes. You would also be able to add any extra properties you need and just follow the examples in the code I provided.

Comment: Ok thank you. I am getting the {StopName = Swanbrough Drive, StopCode = (bridmpj)} (have altered it a bit. How can i just get 

Swanbrough Drive (bridmpj) ?

Also how can I put in a Where condiditon?